# Can't catch IllegalStateException from Google's IAB framework

Tags: java, android, exception, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a Google Play app that uses the [In App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview) v3 framework.

The Google Play [Developer Console](https://developer.android.com/distribute/console/) reports frequent crashes with a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

As a matter of fact, the bulk of my crashes are this illegal state exception. I used the sample code from the IAB framework to handle my in app purchases.

Call stack:

```
  at com.steenriver.armor.util.IabHelper.flagStartAsync (IabHelper.java:824)
  at com.steenriver.armor.util.IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync (IabHelper.java:616)
  at com.steenriver.armor.util.IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync (IabHelper.java:644)
  at com.steenriver.armor.ArmorActivity$1.onIabSetupFinished (ArmorActivity.java:185)
  at com.steenriver.armor.util.IabHelper$1.onServiceConnected (IabHelper.java:262)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected (LoadedApk.java:1625)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1653)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:836)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:232)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6802)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1103)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

To get rid of the crashes, I decided to add exception handling to the code like thus:

```
try
{
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow( this, sku, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload );
} catch( IllegalStateException e )
{
    Log.e( TAG, e.toString() );     // Illegal State: maybe purchase is already in progress?
    enableBuyButton();              // Enable buy button so customer can try again.
}
```

To my amazement, the new version with the try/catch added, still crashes with the same callstack.

Is this because the IllegalStateException can't be caught at all, or something? What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a careful look at your call stack, you'll see that it does not include `launchPurchaseFlow()`. `try` blocks can only catch exceptions from the code that is properly within them, and since your exception is not happening inside any call to `launchPurchaseFlow()`, it is not happening inside your `try`.

`launchPurchaseFlow()` causes the billing state machine to start advancing, but not every purchase operation happens within that function. In other words, the purchase completes "asynchronously".

As you can see from the stack trace, the exception actually occurs during `onServiceConnected()`, which is being called from a `Handler` callback. `launchPurchaseFlow()` has actually already returned by this point; the `try` block is in the past. In order to surround this particular operation with a `try`, you'd actually need to edit an `IabHelper` method, such as `onServiceConnected()`. And this is not recommended, since it seems likely some other mistake in your own code is causing the exception. This is what should be fixed.

Incidentally, I cannot find a version of the v3 billing library where `flagStartAsync()` throws an `IllegalStateException`, so I'm not sure what that's all about.

Obligatory mention: `IabHelper` is apparently no longer supported by Google; you're supposed to use the [billing client library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) instead. The library you're using is no longer referenced by the link you posted.

Comment: Thanks! That was spot on. I am discouraged by having to do yet another IAB upgrade though. I've been through many IAB versions by now. Oh well, I'll just wait for Google's deprecation warning for v3 and upgrade then.